# turning a csv file into a tabular format like excel in python

Tags: python, excel, csv, tkinter

I currently have a CSV file from excel. I would like to import this into python and Tkinter and have it formatted so that it displays it has columns and rows. like it would be displayed in excel. I would also like this to be editable. how can I go about this in python?

Comment: have you worked through a tkinter tutorial yet? That would be the first step. Then, search this site for questions about creating tables in tkinter -- there are several.

Comment: Hi Bryan have worked through many and cannot find anything relating to this

Comment: Nothing? Seriously? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btkinter%5D+table and